# How does the BIOS work in a Xen virtualized environment?

Tags: virtual-machine, boot-loader, amazon-ec2, bios, xen

On a physical machine, the BIOS is located on a chip that sits on the motherboard. How does with work in a [Xen](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Main_Page) virtual environment? Any links to documentation/articles will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS values needed by virtual machines in Xen are handled by xenstore database entries on a per-domain basis. If there are no specific values for your machine's BIOS then set "generic whitebox" BIOS strings in the database, as per the [startup section in the Xen wiki](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/VM_Startup).